# Invoke EJB Stateless Session Bean method from WebSphere Administration console 7.0 or with WebSphere Application Server's utils

Tags: java, ejb, websphere

Is exists the way to invoke the method of stateless session bean from *WebSphere 7.0* console or with helps one of *WebSphere utils*?

I just don't want to do client for testing my EJBs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your EJBs using Universal Test Client. See more details here: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wsadhelp/v5r1m2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.etools.server.core.doc%2Ftopics%2Fcwejbtc.html

Although that link is for WebSphere 5, UTC is still available in WebSphere 7.0. Here is how to enable it:
http://wpcertification.blogspot.com/2011/04/universal-test-client-application.html

Comment: This cool feature available only in **RAD** as I guess. Web browser inside **WebSphere Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse** doesn't open Universal Test Client page. Should I install some additional plugins?

Comment: UTC is just a web application, once it is installed on the server you can access it from the browser and test your EJBs.

Comment: Finally found IBMUTC.ear inside AppServer-Shared. Thank you for the clue.